# how to get following output in oracle using query?

Tags: oracle

I've following data like

```
ano         asal
------------------
1            100
1            150
1            190
2            200
2            240
3            300
3            350
4             400
4             400
4             400
```

i want ans like max sal from 1 ,from 2,3 and 4
o/p like

```
ano       asal
---------------
1          190
2          240
3          390
4          400
4          400
4          400
```

Comment: may be , in expecting answer , for ano 3 , asal is 350

Comment: I think you have a typo for `ano` value 3.  The max looks like it's `350` not `390`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to return the max value of `asal` for each `ano` group, but you want to retain the duplicates in the original table if they exist.  This means you can't just do a simple `GROUP BY`.  But you can use a `GROUP BY` query to identify the max values and then retain those records via an `INNER JOIN`.  Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.ano, t1.asal
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ano, MAX(asal) AS asal
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ano
) t2
    ON t1.ano = t2.ano AND t1.asal = t2.asal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an union the firt  select with group  by

```
select ano, max(asal) 
from my_table 
where ano != 4 
group by ano
union all 
select ano, asal
from my_table 
where ano = 4 
order by ano
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ano, asal
FROM (
    SELECT
        data.*,
        MAX(asal) OVER (PARTITION BY ano) max
    FROM
        data)
WHERE
    asal = max
```